# merge two foreach loop into one and parse it into table row

Tags: php, xml, foreach, html-table

I am working on a php/html code as shown below in which I want to merge two php code into one.

**1st foreach loop :**

```
foreach ( $programs as $program)    {
echo '
<tr>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["series_title"].'</td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["episode_title"].'</td>
   </tr>
';
}
```

**2nd foreach loop :**

```
<?php   foreach ($mp4_files as $file ) {
   ?>
<tr>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file")); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
   }
 ?>
```

The merge should be something like this:

```
 <tr>

   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["series_title"].'</td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;">'.$program["episode_title"].'</td>

   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file")); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file); ?></td>

 </tr>
```

I tried with something like this but it doesn`t seem to work.

```
 foreach(array_combine($programs, $mp4_files) as $f => $n) {
    echo $f.$n;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the tried php code above so that I am able to merge two foreach loop successfully.

Comment: Do `$programs` and `$mp4_files` have the same number of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both arrays have the same keys, you can use the keys of one array to access the matching values of the other. For example:

```
<?php
foreach ($programs as $key => $program)    { 
   $file = $mp4_files[$key];
?>
   <tr>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $program["series_title"]; ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $program["episode_title"]; ?></td>    
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file")); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file); ?></td>    
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When i am doing `print_r($file);` it is showing only one mp4 file whereas it should have three.

Comment: Are there multiple mp4 files per program?

Comment: At present on doing print_r($mp4_files); I am getting *Array ( [2] => 36017P.mp4 [4] => 36031P.mp4 [6] => hello.mp4 )*

Comment: what is in `print_r($programs)`?

Comment: Every mp4 has one *series_title* and *episode_title*

Comment: Can you show me the result of `print_r($programs)` for the set of mp4 files you gave the data for?

Comment: One doing *print_r($program)* from the *1st foreach loop*, I am getting the following https://jsfiddle.net/1tk4nseo/ Sorry I pasted in jsfiddle as the output was quite big.

Comment: 1st mp4 has *1st array value*, 2nd mp4 has *2nd array value* and 3rd mp4 has *3rd array value* from jsfiddle.

Comment: I understand what is happening. On printing  *print_r($key);* it is showing *0 1 2*  and it is taking *[2] => 36017P.mp4* from *print_r($mp4_files)*

Comment: Thats the reason why I am getting only one mp4.

Comment: Assuming you need `$mp4_files` to be indexed as 0,1,2, then prior to the loop use `$mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);`

Comment: @flash I'm sorry about the lack of response - I had to deal with something away from my computer. I see the problem was what I suspected: that `$programs` and `$mp4_files` and different keys; that's why I was asking to see the `print_r` results. I'm glad Nigel was able to point you at the right thing to do to solve it.

Comment: @Nick I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533375/change-button-text-in-js-ajax-after-mp4-mp3-conversion-in-php). Its not similar but involving the same code which I have used here. I am wondering if you can have a look